# Is it, in some way, possible to actually Copy&Paste text in the (Java) shell that's started up when running the nodes?

Tags: java, shell, kotlin, corda

I have searched the Corda tagged questions to find an answer but found none. And neither could I find a satisfying answer on Google.

So the problem I have is this: I am working on Corda together with a colleague of mine and we're trying out lots of things. But we also have to constantly type in the whole command 
(like: *`start IOUFlow iouValue: 99, otherParty: "O=PartyB,L=New York,C=US"`*) which is quite the hassle if you're doing it a couple of times in short succession.

Is there any way to actually paste text in the Shell that's started when running the nodes? And for that matter: is there also a way to actually return to the previous line in the shell after you're on the next line?

Ps, no, our company unfortunately does not (yet) issue MacBooks...

Comment: Looking at the docs for Corda, it looks like its shell is based on [CraSH](http://www.crashub.org/) ([docs](http://www.crashub.org/1.3/reference.html)), which supports accessing command history using the up and down arrow keys.

Comment: Other keys combos that you might try (I can't find these anywhere in the CraSH docs, but they are popular among shells): Ctrl-Shift-C/Ctrl-Shift-V or Ctrl-Insert/Shift-Insert for copy/paste, TAB for autocompletion, Ctrl-R for reverse history search.

Answer (score 0):

You can right click in the shell to paste whatever is currently in your clipboard.

As mentioned in the comments, the shell also supports the up and down arrow keys to move through the command history.

Alternatively, you could write your own RPC client or REST interface to interact with the node. Take a look at:

Client RPC API
https://docs.corda.net/tutorial-clientrpc-api.html

REST interface in the IOU app
https://github.com/corda/cordapp-example/blob/release-V2/kotlin-source/src/main/kotlin/com/example/api/ExampleApi.kt